# Toggle Line-through on click in paragraph lines

Tags: javascript, html, css, line-through

I am trying to create an on-click `line-through` for a bunch of words (item #1, item #2, item #3). I want it to be line-through when clicked, and if the same word is clicked a second time the line-through should disappear again.

```
<p>
Item #1<br>
Item #2<br>
Item #3<br>
</p>
```

I would prefer css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each item text should be wrapped by a `span` to change its properties.

Here is a simple demo using `JQuery`:

```js
$("#parg").find("span").click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("line-through");
});
```

```css
.line-through{
     text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="parg">
<span>Item #1</span><br>
<span>Item #2</span><br>
<span>Item #3</span><br>
</p>
```

Comment: This works on here and in JSFiddle, but when I add it to my own website it does not. Do you have any idea why? Anything in particular to pay attention to when adding this code?

Comment: @micks88 make sure to reference ``JQuery``. Add this ``<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`` to the ``head`` in the ``html`` file.

Comment: It still does not work unfortunately, but that is my problem as I can tell it is working here :)